# git changes in CSV Including Filename

Tags: git, csv, github, gitlab

How to fetch file-name in git ?

**`git log --since='last month' --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ar,%s' > log.csv`**

Hear i need to get file name of the as another column?

I tried all the values from this [site](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats).

Comment: i tried all the below comments but failed  '%H','%h','%T','%t','%P','%p','%an','%aN','%ae','%aE','%ad','%aD','%ar','%at','%ai','%aI','%cn','%cN','%ce','%cE','%cd','%cD','%cr','%ct','%ci','%cI','%d','%D','%e','%s','%f','%b','%B','%N','%GG','%G?','%GS','%GK','%gD','%gd','%gn','%gN','%ge','%gE','%gs'
,'%Cred','%Cgreen','%Cblue','%Creset','%C(…​)','%m','%n','%%','%x00','%w([<w>[,<i1>[,<i2>]]])','%<(<N>[,trunc|ltrunc|mtrunc])','%<|(<N>)','%>(<N>)','%>|(<N>)','%>>(<N>)','%>>|(<N>)','%><(<N>)','%><|(<N>)'

Comment: Perhaps you want `git log <option> ...` where `<option>` is one of `--name-only`, `-name-status`, or `--stat`... I don't think you can get the file names in a different column, though, because `git log` walks _commits_, which do not always have a 1-1 correspondence with files...

Comment: @twalberg I need is File name + UserName + Date any format is ok  for me how can i get these ?

Comment: You can do `git log --since='last month' --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ar,%s' --name-only`, but you'll have to post-process the output to join the user/date information to each filename that was touched in the commit. That's about as close as you'll get with native `git`. `awk` or `python` or `perl` would be useful for the post-processing...